# Duplicate table rows rendered in React-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am in the process of creating a react element for a line item in a table. I am using React-rails for this and am running into some strange behavior.

I have one record in my database and my react component is listing duplicate entries. This is what is being rendered in the DOM.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div data-react-class="questions/QuestionLineItem" data-react-props="{&quot;prompt&quot;:&quot;What year was the NFL founded?&quot;,&quot;uuid&quot;:&quot;f85c2f85-95d8-4037-963f-d1503b24123b&quot;}" data-hydrate="t">
<tr><td>f85c2f85-95d8-4037-963f-d1503b24123b</td><td>What year was the NFL founded?</td></tr>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UUID</th>
            <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-reactroot=""><td>f85c2f85-95d8-4037-963f-d1503b24123b</td><td>What year was the NFL founded?</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

One record is being rendered correct into the table but the other one is floating at the top not nested in the table. My item component is quite simple.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
class QuestionLineItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.uuid}</td>
        <td>{this.props.prompt}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

QuestionLineItem.propTypes = {
  prompt: PropTypes.string
};

export default QuestionLineItem;
```

The view is just a simple table and loops over all of the items in the active record collection.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UUID</th>
            <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% @questions.each do |q| %>
            <%= react_component('questions/QuestionLineItem', { prompt: q.prompt, uuid: q.uuid }, { prerender: true} ) %>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Can anybody explain this behavior?

The questions controller contains only an index action.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationsController 
    def index
        @questions = Question.all
    end
end
```

[image]

Comment: How are you assigning @questions? Can we see your controller code please?

Comment: your html view looks normal to me(same with controller and react code), where are duplicates that you mentioned?a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: @kasperite `QuestionLineItem` is rendered twice, first inside `div.table-responsive`, second time properly in `tbody`

Comment: I don't know about react-rails, but I would look up the documentation on the parameters to `react_component`, especially `prerender`. Also try changing to `<%` instead of `<%=`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `<React.Fragment>` to the output of your React Component?
It would look like this:

```
class QuestionLineItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <tr>
          <td>{this.props.uuid}</td>
          <td>{this.props.prompt}</td>
        </tr>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

For reference, here you can read about React.Fragments more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)